# Adding new trigger to "SynchronizeTime" scheduled task

Tags: windows, windows-7, scheduled-tasks, command-prompt

We have a till based system that starts up on boot of Windows 7.

One core task is to ensure that the time is synchronized and correct. currently, there is the built in scheduled task to check this at 01:00 every Sunday.

I have added a new trigger, to perform this on start up.

We now have 1000 machines that we need to deploy the same trigger to, and I'm struggling to use the SCHTASKS to add this trigger to the existing task.

If I try

```
SCHTASKS /CHANGE /TN "SynchronizeTime" /SC ONSTART
```

I get

```
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '/SC'
```

How should I be adding the new trigger via the cmd line?

The plan is to deploy and run a batch file for this change across the estate.

Comment: there seems to be no way to `/Change` the frequency of an existing task, better create a new one and delete the existing one.